# Защита Canvas от пользовательских скриптов

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, разработка-игр, canvas, защита

На данный момент я делаю небольшую браузерную игрушку, типа как Final Fantasy, используя jCanvas. И вот возник вопрос о защите от пользовательских скриптов, ведь кто угодно может ввести

```
canvas.setLayerGroup('player', {
    x: moveX,
    y: moveY
});
```

и он сможет переместиться за стенку, на другой берег реки и т.д.
Кто может подсказать в каком направлении мне смотреть что-бы защититься от подобных моментов?

Comment: Такая защита вряд ли есть. Но думаю что мало программистов будет играть в такое ))))))

Comment: А как перемещение иконки игрока на экране повлияет на его координаты в логике игры? Или вы прямо в canvas их и храните?

Comment: Почему так? В чем проблема?)

Comment: Я сейчас только разглядываю о вариантах хранения координат игрока. В канвасе я наверняка не буду их хранить. А вот на сервере - скорее всего. В планах создавать объект игрока и используя serialize() хранить его на сервере. При передвижении подымать файл, проверять реально ли пройти такое расстояние и передвигать его на указанное расстояние.

Comment: Тогда непонятно, в чем, собственно, проблема? :) Ну окажется изображение игрока на другом берегу реки, но сервер-то знает, где игрок на самом деле и не даст, скажем, взять предмет, лежащий на этом самом другом берегу.

Comment: Мне интересно правильное ли я выбрал направление))

Comment: Возможно есть же и другие варианты реализации подобного, о которых я еще не знаю. Такие есть или нет?

Comment: Ну, основное правило тут - не доверять ничему, что приходит от клиента, соответственно все проверки на допустимость того или иного действия должны происходить на сервере. То есть, условно говоря, от клиента должно приходить не сообщение "игрок открыл ключом сундук и получил 100 монет", а сообщение "игрок хочет открыть сундук". А сервер уже проверяет, есть ли у игрока ключ, есть ли в этом месте сундук, и что в нем находится.